# Return brackets as string with shortcut

Tags: autohotkey

in my autohotkey script i have

```
:*:eclick:: .addEventListener("click",function(){});
```

but `{}` is always ignore, is it possible to return `{}` as text or is it protected ?!

Thanks,gui

Comment: You might want to consider sending appropriate line breaks/whitespaces like this: `.addEventListener("click", function() {\`n});`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When sending special characters, it's best to use [raw mode](http://ahkscript.org/docs/Hotstrings.htm#Options) in order to ensure that the keys won't be misinterpreted:

```
#Hotstring r
:*:eclick:: .addEventListener("click",function(){});
```

Alternatively, you could use `SendRaw`:

```
:*:eclick:: 
    SendRaw, %A_SPACE%.addEventListener("click",function(){});
return
```